# How to use parameters as filters in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I think this is a simple question, but I somehow cannot sort it out. I have a List < SomeClass > that will be returned by an MVC controller. But, I want to filter the results server side. So suppose class is like:

```
public SomeClass()
{
    string option1;
    string option2;
    int indexing;
}
```

Now I want to do a GET request, but the results need to be filtered on option1. So I can query the database properly. So I tried to jsonconvert.serialize an instance of the class with option1 set to 'something', but how can I deliver this to my MVC GET method? With httpclient there is no content, with httpWebRequest and writing it into a stream I have the error 'no content can be send with this verb', where verb is set to GET.

I think I am missing a basic thing here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the signature of the action method on your controller that you are trying to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep your action as a GET, you need to call the action with the right querystring paramters i.e. /ActionName?option1=somevalue&option2=othervalue

and your action:

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ActionName(SomeClass someclass)

or post the json option and chance your HttpGetverb to HttpPost

Comment: So what if I have like 6 columns to filter? With types like guid, timespan, string, int, etc. If these are simple types, can I only specify them in the Uri? GET does not work with a body? That makes a long Uri then ... But that is by design? And what if you have custom classes within SomeClass?

Comment: or just use verb POST? Are there any downsides on using POST where GET looks like a more proper alternative?

Comment: Changed verb to post, seems a quite common approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's simple, you can use Json Result:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetListObjects(string filter)
{
    //getdata items
    var objects =
    from item in items
    where (string)item.option1 == filter
    select item;

    return Json(objects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: but the point is here a user may want to filter on two or three columns